# process local php file on server without given direct ip or domain name

Tags: php

I have the following php file which is for fetching and displaying image read a database

```
<?php

require_once('database.php');
$db = new Database();

$id = $_GET['id'];
$order = $_GET['order'];


// do some validation here to ensure id is safe

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo pg_unescape_bytea($db->getImageById($id, $order));
?>
```

This file works fine, however below is how I am using it

```
$img_binary = file_get_contents('http://example.com/helper/getImageById.php?id=' . $id . '&order=1', false);
$img_base64 = base64_encode($img_binary);
```

I'm trying to find a way that I would no longer have to provide hard-coded information such as `example.com`, I want to be able to move all the files to another server and/or domain name without having to change the server ip. This is in a script that will be used by multiple domain names.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: I don't get it what you saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` instead of domain name.